# Fetch html which is loaded dynamically? python

Tags: python, html, fetch, web-crawler

I am writing a crawler in python which must extract the links to the PDFS listed in this page:

http://www.peekyou.com/barack_obama

(scroll down, there is a "documents" section with links to pdfs. )

The problem is that the "documents" section is loaded in background, after a few seconds, probably in javascript. And the function I am using to fetch the html page does not fetch that section.

To fetch the html, I have been given this code:

```
        ...
        req = urllib2.Request(url)            
        req.add_header('User-agent', random.choice(LISTAGENT))                        
        page = urllib2.urlopen(req)                                        
        if page.info().getmaintype() == "text":
            html = page.read()
            ...
```

which does not fetch that section, as I said.

What is the proper way to deal with my problem? Is there an API I can use? Thank you.

Comment: Using a crawler that understands JavaScript and exposes live DOM is the only way to achieve (somewhat) consistent results of late-loaded AJAX sections. If the section is behind a user-initiated AJAX call and there is no way to follow it automatically (e.g. via `#!`), then the bot is pretty much SOL. (Or, it could be like a kid in a plane cockpit and poke every button it sees ..)

Comment: thanks, and where do I start writing a crawler that understands javascript and exposes live DOM?

Comment: You can look at [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) this will load a page in a headless copy of WebKit and expose the DOM via JavaScript.

Comment: You can try: https://github.com/niwibe/phantompy